# Why does specifying fill in an Aesthetic mapping change the figure in the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

When trying highlight a part of a plot, I got an output I didn't expect.

This is the code I'm using to plot the density function of student grades from my dataset.

```
grades <- student_data$G3
q_aprox = function(x) return (qnorm(x, mean(grades), sd(grades)))
ggplot(student_data, aes(x = G3)) +

# -- IMPORTANT PART BEGIN -- #
    geom_density(
         color = 'steelblue',
         alpha = 0.3,
         position = 'stack'
     ) + 
    geom_density(
         aes(fill = q_aprox(0.025) < G3 & G3 < q_aprox(0.975)),
         alpha = 0.3,
         position = 'stack'
     ) + theme_minimal()
# -- IMPORTANT PART END -- #
```

Unexpectedly, the plot I got from the first `geom_density` is different than the one I got from the second `geom_density`. I expected that, since the `x` and `y` mappings are left untouched, the plots would be the same.
Why doesn't this happen?

`grades`, or `student_data$G3`, is a numeric vector of size 395 with discrete values from 0 up to 20.

Here's the plot that's produced from the previous code

[Output Plot - Not enough reputation to post images, sorry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30A7J.png)

The left tail on the second call is bigger than the one on the first. Also, the output in general seems to be "more spiked".

I recently watched part 1 of [`ggplot2`'s workshop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h29g21z0a68&t=765s) on YouTube in preparation for this college assignment. That's more or less my knowledge level regarding `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the `fill` aesthetic with a discrete variable triggers heuristics in ggplot2 that will automatically group your data. The densities are calculed per group, and densities integrate to 1. Therefore, if you calculate two densities of two groups of unequal sizes, densities still integrate to 1, so the the area of the densities does not reflect the unequal group sizes.

Below is an example of two groups, wherein group A is 10x as large as group B and the groups have different means. You'll notice that if we don't group the data, the resulting density peaks at -1: the center/mean of group A. However, when we auto-group the data with the `fill` aesthetic, both densities will peak at their own means, but the area of group B is as large as group A (it continuous behind the blue/green density).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(rnorm(1000, -1), rnorm(100, 1)),
  group = rep(c("A", "B"), c(1000, 100))
)

g1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_density()

g2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, fill = group)) +
  geom_density()

g1 | g2
```

[image]

If you want to retain proportions to the group sizes, you can use `y = after_stat(count)` to use the computed variable `count`, which is the density estimate (which integrates to 1) times the number of observations. You can read about computed variables in the documentation under the header "computed variables" in for example `?geom_density`.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, fill = group)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(count)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>